# Non-zero non-unitary ring homomorphisms [collecting examples]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

> I am interested of finding examples of non-zero homomorphisms $f:R\to S$ of rings with unity such that $f(1_R)\neq 1_S$.

I will provide one example and I will be glad if others can also give examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let be $f:\mathbb Z \to M_2(\mathbb Z); f(a)= \left( \array{a&0\\0&0}\right) $ then $f$ is ring homomorphism and $f(1)=\left(\array{1&0\\0&0}\right) \ne \left(\array{1&0\\0&1}\right)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. Define $f:R\to S$ by $f(n)=(n,0)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f$ is a nonzero homomorphism but
$$f(1_R)=f(1)=(1,0)\neq (1,1)=1_S.$$

Comment: You can imitate your example for any general ring $R$. Define $f\colon R\to R\times R$ by $f(x) =(x,0)$.

Comment: @P Vanchinathan Thanks. It is a nice observation.

Comment: You are asking for "rng" homomorphisms (by some definitions, _by definition_ $1_R\mapsto 1_S$).  A further type of example is the homomorphism $f:R\to S:x\mapsto ex$, where $S=eR$ and $e$ is a nontrivial idempotent element of $R$.